# 'int?' is not identical to 'Uint8' in swift

Tags: swift

```
func add(numbers: Int...) -> Int?
{
    var total:Int?
    for  i in  numbers
    {
        total += i  // >> 'int?' is not identical to 'Uint8' in swift 

    }
    return total
}
```

numbers is Int, why total can't be assign to Int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting might be a little deceiving. The underlying issue here is that you declared a variable `total` of type `Int?`, but never actually assigned it a value. Since `total` hasn't been given an integer value, it doesn't make sense to try to increment it by `i`.

You can fix this by initializing the `total` variable to zero. It's also worth noting that your total and return type do not need to be optionals here, since you're taking a variable number of non-optional Ints as input, meaning that your inputs will always have a total when added together.

If you're dead set on keeping optionals involved here, the following code will work.

```
func add(numbers: Int...) -> Int? {
    var total: Int? = 0

    for i in numbers {
        total! += i
    }

    return total
}
```

Notice that the variable `total` is being forcibly unwrapped on incrementation. This will crash if total is ever nil (i.e. not given an initial value). But this **really** isn't necessary. As I explained above, there is no need to use optionals here at all. Instead, I recommend implementing the function like this.

```
func add(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var total = 0

    for i in numbers {
        total += i
    }

    return total
}
```

If you're interested in alternatives to your function that are perhaps more Swifty, you can rewrite your entire function like this:

```
func add(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    return reduce(numbers, 0, +)
}
```

Comment: it seems total can't be 'Int?'    'var total:Int? = 0' also not work.

Comment: @starcwl Can you elaborate on that? If you're getting an error on the incrementing line, it's because you aren't unwrapping the optional first (i.e. `total! += i`). If the error is on return, it's because I changed the return type to `Int`. Either way, your `total` variable shouldn't be optional anyway.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I only want to know what's the problem with the code, not the implementation of the function.

Comment: I know total shouldn't be optional. But if you mean it can't be optional?

Comment: @starcwl It can, and I've edited my post to reflect this. It just shouldn't be optional since there is no possible case where the sum of non-optional Ints is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work anyway. You try to add a number to a variable you haven't initialized yet. So the return will always be `nil` So change that:

```
var total:Int?
```

to that:

```
var total:Int? = 0
```

But you could also remove the `?` because it's not necessary, because you will take non-optional parameters.

```
var total:Int = 0
```

Comment: 'var total:Int? = 0'  won't work and also has error.

Answer (score 0):

Total is not `Int` is `Optional(Int)`, you have to unwrap for it to become `Int`

You can do this in 2 ways, faster and safer:

Faster: `return total!`

Safer:

```
if let total = total {return total}
```

Hope this helps, have fun with Swift!